Cannot find Azure SQL Database in Visual Studio

I have created a SQL database on Azure. When I go to publish my database in Visual Studios I get the message "No connection to display"
the database on azure says its online and available. I have been able publish my web app to azure, but this isn't recognized.

SQL is a language, so I removed the  tag. Probably you should add a dbms tag instead.

I think this is a (yet another) new bug to SSDT introduced in VS 17.10.x - it started happening to me in the past month too.

Follow the below approach to publish Azure SQL Database in Visual Studio:

Right click on database project in Solution Explorer and click Import and select Database as shown below:



Click on Select Connection and provide required details to connect with the database:



Click on Start to connect with the database successfully.



Below is another approach to connect Azure SQL Database:

Click on View in Visual Studio and select Server Explorer.


Click on Connect to Database under Server Explorer and fill the required details to test the connection.


It successfully connects to the Azure SQL Database as shown in the below output




I am able to connect with a connection string, I'm really wondering why I can't use the azure drop down to select the database

Refer this document for more information.
